# Proving independent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

According to Statistics Canada, a random person in Canada has

- a probability of $4/5$ to live to at least 70 years old and
- a probability of $1/2$ to live to at least 80 years old

Thatcher (a random person in Canada) has just celebrated her 70-th birthday. What is the
probability that Thatcher will celebrate her 80-th birthday?

There are two events here; $A$: lives at least 70 years old and $B$: lives at least 80 years old.

It is quite obvious that the probability of Thatcher celebrating her 80-th birthday is $1/2$, since both events are independent of each other. But how can I show that my answer is true.

Comment: I guess there is not enough information to find the answer.

Comment: Although we do not have enough information your statement is probably not true. If those probabilities are estimated for the whole population, then there are people included who have died before they are 70 years old. This means that, given that you're already 70 years old, the probably will be higher to reach 80.

Comment: Seems to be a woman, on average women live longer. But if we don't complain too much about such things, let $A$ be the event reach $70$, $B$ the event reach $80$. We want $\Pr(B|A)$, which is $\frac{\Pr(B\cap A)}{\Pr(A)}$. Or else we can use an informal calculation, Out of $1000$ people, probably the number reaching $70$ is not terribly far from $800$, the number reaching $80$ is not far from $500$, so the probability should be about $\frac{500}{800}$.

Comment: So there is absolutely no way of finding the probability of Thatcher celebrating her 80-th birthday based on the information provided?

Comment: I was wrong, there is enough information. You just have to calculate a conditional probability, which is probably not the same as the unconditional one as I explained in the previous comment. So letting $A$ and $B$ be the same as in Andre Nicolas' comment we see that $P(B|A) = \frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(B)}{P(A)} = \frac{1}{2}/\frac{4}{5} = \frac{5}{8}$. We see that $P(B\cap A) = P(B)$ because $B$ implies $A$, or $A\subset B$.

Comment: Unless the question literally means, what are the chances that Thatcher chooses to have a celebration for those birthdays ... but in the more likely sense, what are the chances that Thatcher lives to be 70/80 years old, it's quite clear that they're not at all independent.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. It looks like B is dependent on A. $5/8$ should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would say .625, but then I'm often wrong  on probabilites.

The given probabilities are assumed to relate to a person at birth, and you have to intuitively feel that if someone has lived a long time then they have a better chance to get to 80 that someone just starting out on life's path - take it to the extreme, if my 80th birthday is tomorrow then I've a pretty good chance of making it !

So, what is the probability that someone who has attained the year of 70 will attain the year of 80 - a conditional probability: P(a|b) = P(a & b) / P(b).

You have to get to 70 before you get to 80, so P(80 and 70) = P(80)

So P(80 | 70) = P(80) / P(70) = .5/ .8 = .625.

This seems to be the same as comment posted above by Andre.

Comment: P.S.as I understand it the events are NOT independent. The probablility that Thatcher reaches 80 is qute likely independent of Wilson reaching 70, but not of Thatcher reaching 70. If Thatcher doesn't reach 70 then she doesn't reach 80 either !